# Build error when enable the Push Notifications

Tags: codenameone

I am working with CodeRad 2 Java application generated by Codename One Initializr. Now I am starting to work with Push Notification following the steps in implementing PushCallback.

```
public class WhosPlays  extends ApplicationController implements PushCallback {

............
............. 
.............

    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();

        // Register device to receive push
        Display.getInstance().callSerially(() ->
                Display.getInstance().registerPush());
        // The rest of your start() logic....
    }
    @Override
    public void push(String value) {
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void registeredForPush(String deviceID) {
        // Successfully registered device for push!!
        DeviceInfo.devicePushID = Push.getPushKey();
        DeviceInfo.devicePushID2 = deviceID;
        // Store this DEVICE_ID for later use
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void pushRegistrationError(String err, int errCode) {
        WP_message.errorMessage("Error, Push Registration " + err);

    }
.................................................
.................................................
.................................................
}
```

After this change, I am getting Build errors.  With Android right away.

```
Found hyp.beamId
Tried to start hyperlog but failed: Failed to start hyperlog: Cannot run program "hyp": error=2, No such file or directory
User-level: 9000
Request Args:
```

With iOS only when I set the codename1.arg.ios.includePush=true

```
Found hyp.beamId
Tried to start hyperlog but failed: Failed to start hyperlog: Cannot run program "hyp": error=2, No such file or directory
Executing: /usr/local/bin/pod --version Executing with timeout -1
Ignoring ffi-1.15.5 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.5
Ignoring sqlite3-1.4.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine sqlite3 --version 1.4.2
1.11.2
Process return code is 0
Pods version: Ignoring ffi-1.15.5 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.5
Ignoring sqlite3-1.4.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine sqlite3 --version 1.4.2
1.11.2

User-level: 9000
```

Thanks in Advance for your help

I tried to remove dependencies that I don't need.

BTW I am using tweet-app-ui-kit-lib

Answer (score 0):

This probably relates to the [work we did here](https://www.reddit.com/r/cn1/comments/11cmkp9/changes_to_android_play_services_versions/).

Google now requires that you explicitly select the play services you wish to include so for your case the build hint:

```
android.playService.gcm=true
```

Would probably solve the problem. If not please contact the chat in the website with the full error log so we can go over it.

Comment: I contacted the website chat. They helped me to understand how to read the error file that basically says google-services.json not found. I moved the file to the android\src\main\resources for IntelliJ IDEA.